# How to show tooltip on movable listbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have the following control on my aspx page

```html
<asp:ListBox ID = "X" runat="Server" CssClass = "listbox"></asp:ListBox>
```

I have to show a tooltip on the list item, where items are movable means i can change the position of any item on UI.

I have added my custom method on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(){
  foreach(ListItem li in X {.
    string tip = li.Text;
    li.Attribute.Add("title",tip) })}
```

But the issue is tooltip is coming only for the loaded page, As soon as I change the position of the list item it still shows the old tooltip.

Any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Do you use any custom tooltip code, or are you relying on the default browser behavior?

Comment: I want to show the tooltip on the mouseover, I am not sure how it will work.

Comment: "Show tooltip on mouseover" is the default browser behavior. Are you using custom tooltip code?

Comment: So I will get all the list items on page load, I need to show all those list item texts as a tooltip. I don't have any custom tooltip code

Comment: With no custom tooltip software, the "show tooltip on mouseover" simply works by displaying the contents of the element's `title` attribute. If this is not working for you, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this not working.

Comment: list item will come on page load, how will I add title next to them?

Comment: Set an element's `title` attribute any way you want: [HTMLElement.title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/title)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "change the position of any item on UI" means reordering the `<li>` elements, the tooltip info should go with the `<li>`, as that is taken from the li's `title` attribute.

Unless you have some sort of custom tooltip code.

As demonstrated here, the tooltip text stays with its `li`:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
btn.onclick = function () {
  const [first, second, third] = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
  ul.insertBefore(third, first);
}
```

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button>Move</button>

<ul>
  <li title="first item">First Item</li>
  <li title="second item">Second Item</li>
  <li title="third item">Third Item</li>
</ul>
```